# How to implement request decryption and response encryption in Play application?

Tags: scala, encryption, playframework, playframework-2.0, loops

Given

```
trait CipherService {
  def decryptData(data: Array[Byte])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[DecryptionError \/ Array[Byte]
  def encryptEncrypt(data: Array[Byte)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[EncryptionError \/ Array[Byte]]
}
```

How can I implement request decryption and response encryption using `EssentialFilter`? It feel like I'm stuck with `Enumeratee` and `Iteratee` API.

Answer (score 0):

Iteratees and Enumeratees are pretty much the way to go when you're down to the limit of byte chunks.  Encryption is a very low level operation, and very hard to do right, so the tools are likewise low level, small and precise.

Because encrypting and decrypting data is so hard to do right, most web frameworks rely on HTTPS rather than implement it in the application layer.

If you're working with HTTP, then using nginx with OpenSSL configured according to bettercrypto.org: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ConfiguringHttps

If you're using security internally and you want to encrypt data over the wire, you should use ipsec in transport mode.

Comment: We already use HTTPS, but we have custom encryption of some headers and body atop of HTTP.

Comment: Okay -- what you can do (although this is still experimental) is use the Reactive Streams API in 2.4.x: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ReactiveStreamsIntegration

Comment: I've figured it out yesterday. Gonna post answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
trait CipherService {
  def decryptData(data: Array[Byte])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[DecryptionError \/ Array[Byte]]
  def encryptData(data: Array[Byte])(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[EncryptionError \/ Array[Byte]]
}

trait BodyEncryptionFilter extends EssentialFilter with Results {

  import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._

  val cipher: CipherService

  def apply(next: EssentialAction): EssentialAction = new EssentialAction {
    override def apply(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Iteratee[Array[Byte], Result] =
      Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]().mapM { encryptedBody => // Collect body bytes
        cipher.decryptData(encryptedBody) // Decrypt data
          .toEitherT   // Monad transformer
          .flatMapF { decryptedBody =>
            Enumerator(decryptedBody).run(next(requestHeader)) // Feed decrypted data to filter/action chain
              .flatMap { result => // Here is the action result
                result.body.run(Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]()) //Collect result body data
                  .flatMap { body =>
                    cipher.encryptData(body) // Ecnrypt body data
                      .toEitherT
                      .map { encryptedBody =>
                        result.copy(body = Enumerator(encryptedBody)) // Wrap it with Enumerator and copy result
                      }
                      .leftMap(_ => BadRequest("Encryption error")) // You will probably want proper error handling
                      .merge
                  }
              }
            .map(_.right)
          }
          .leftMap(_ => BadRequest("Encryption error"))
          .merge
      }
    }
}
```